# PySpark: Create incrementing group column counter

Tags: pyspark

How can I generate the expected value, ExpectedGroup such that the same value exists when True, but changes and increments by 1, when we run into a False statement in `cond1`.

Consider:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
            ['A', '2019-01-01', 'P', 'O', 2, None],
            ['A', '2019-01-02', 'O', 'O', 5, 1],
            ['A', '2019-01-03', 'O', 'O', 10, 1],
            ['A', '2019-01-04', 'O', 'P', 4, None],
            ['A', '2019-01-05', 'P', 'P', 300, None],
            ['A', '2019-01-06', 'P', 'O', 2, None],
            ['A', '2019-01-07', 'O', 'O', 5, 2],
            ['A', '2019-01-08', 'O', 'O', 10, 2],
            ['A', '2019-01-09', 'O', 'P', 4, None],
            ['A', '2019-01-10', 'P', 'P', 300, None],
            ['B', '2019-01-01', 'P', 'O', 2, None],
            ['B', '2019-01-02', 'O', 'O', 5, 3],
            ['B', '2019-01-03', 'O', 'O', 10, 3],
            ['B', '2019-01-04', 'O', 'P', 4, None],
            ['B', '2019-01-05', 'P', 'P', 300, None],
            ]),
                           ['ID', 'Time', 'FromState', 'ToState', 'Hours', 'ExpectedGroup'])
```

```
# condition statement
cond1 = (df.FromState == 'O') & (df.ToState == 'O')
df = df.withColumn('condition', cond1.cast("int"))
df = df.withColumn('conditionLead', F.lead('condition').over(Window.orderBy('ID', 'Time')))
df = df.na.fill(value=0, subset=["conditionLead"])
df = df.withColumn('finalCondition', ( (F.col('condition') == 1) &  (F.col('conditionLead') == 1)).cast('int'))
```

```
# working pandas option:
# cond1 = ( (df.FromState == 'O') & (df.ToState == 'O')  )
# df['ExpectedGroup'] = (cond1.shift(-1) & cond1).cumsum().mask(~cond1)

# other working option:
# cond1 = ( (df.FromState == 'O') & (df.ToState == 'O')  )
# df['ExpectedGroup'] = (cond1.diff()&cond1).cumsum().where(cond1)


# failing here
windowval = (Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Time').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
df = df.withColumn('ExpectedGroup2', F.sum(F.when(cond1, F.col('finalCondition'))).over(windowval))
```

Comment: I am not totally understand your logic but is this what you are looking for?  `windowval = (Window.orderBy('ID', 'Time').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
df.withColumn('ExpectedGroup2', F.when(cond1, F.sum(F.col('finalCondition')).over(windowval)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same logic shown in your Pandas code, use Window [lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) function to get the previous value of `cond1`, set the flag to `1` only when the current `cond1` is true and the previous `cond1` is false, and then do the cumsum based on `cond1`, see below code(BTW, you probably want to add `ID` to partitionBy clause of the WindSpec, in that case the last `ExpectedGroup1` should be `1` instead of `3`):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('ID', 'time')

df_new = (df.withColumn('cond1', (F.col('FromState')=='O') & (F.col('ToState')=='O'))
    .withColumn('f', F.when(F.col('cond1') & (~F.lag(F.col('cond1')).over(w)),1).otherwise(0))
    .withColumn('ExpectedGroup1', F.when(F.col('cond1'), F.sum('f').over(w)))
)
df_new.show()
+---+----------+---------+-------+-----+-------------+-----+---+--------------+
| ID|      Time|FromState|ToState|Hours|ExpectedGroup|cond1|  f|ExpectedGroup1|
+---+----------+---------+-------+-----+-------------+-----+---+--------------+
|  A|2019-01-01|        P|      O|    2|         null|false|  0|          null|
|  A|2019-01-02|        O|      O|    5|            1| true|  1|             1|
|  A|2019-01-03|        O|      O|   10|            1| true|  0|             1|
|  A|2019-01-04|        O|      P|    4|         null|false|  0|          null|
|  A|2019-01-05|        P|      P|  300|         null|false|  0|          null|
|  A|2019-01-06|        P|      O|    2|         null|false|  0|          null|
|  A|2019-01-07|        O|      O|    5|            2| true|  1|             2|
|  A|2019-01-08|        O|      O|   10|            2| true|  0|             2|
|  A|2019-01-09|        O|      P|    4|         null|false|  0|          null|
|  A|2019-01-10|        P|      P|  300|         null|false|  0|          null|
|  B|2019-01-01|        P|      O|    2|         null|false|  0|          null|
|  B|2019-01-02|        O|      O|    5|            3| true|  1|             3|
|  B|2019-01-03|        O|      O|   10|            3| true|  0|             3|
|  B|2019-01-04|        O|      P|    4|         null|false|  0|          null|
|  B|2019-01-05|        P|      P|  300|         null|false|  0|          null|
+---+----------+---------+-------+-----+-------------+-----+---+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to create a group column counter in PySpark?

To create a group column counter in PySpark, we can use the **Window** function and the **row_number** function. The **Window** function allows us to define a partitioning and ordering criteria for the rows, and the **row_number** function returns the position of the row within the window.

For example, suppose we have a PySpark DataFrame called df with the following data:

| id | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X |
| 2 | B | X |
| 3 | C | Y |
| 4 | D | Y |
| 5 | E | Z |

We want to create a new column called group_counter that assigns a number to each row within the same category, starting from 1. To do this, we can use the following code:

```py
# Import the required modules
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

# Define the window specification
window = Window.partitionBy("category").orderBy("id")

# Create the group column counter
df = df.withColumn("group_counter", row_number().over(window))

# Show the result
df.show()
```

The output of the code is:

| id | name | category | group_counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 1 |
| 2 | B | X | 2 |
| 3 | C | Y | 1 |
| 4 | D | Y | 2 |
| 5 | E | Z | 1 |

As we can see, the group_counter column increments by 1 for each row within the same category, and resets to 1 when the category changes.

### Why is creating a group column counter useful?

Creating a group column counter can be useful for various purposes, such as:

- Ranking the rows within a group based on some criteria, such as sales, ratings, or popularity.
- Assigning labels or identifiers to the rows within a group, such as customer segments, product categories, or order numbers.
- Performing calculations or aggregations based on the group column counter, such as cumulative sums, averages, or percentages.